plsql procedure statement ignored
I have written this procedure and when I try to run it, I get an error "ORA-00933". I have added the update statements and after this the error occurs. Before that it worked.
What could be the issue?
DECLARE 
---values---
   v_sidcount sitetb.sid%type;
   v_sid sitetb.sid%type;
   v_cid sitetb.cid%type := 46;
   v_sptid sitetb.sptid%type := 215;

BEGIN 

---count---
SELECT count(sid) into v_sidcount FROM sitetb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT sid FROM kam_report_ttn
  WHERE sid = sitetb.sid
) and cid = v_cid and sptid = v_sptid;

---find all data---
SELECT max(sid) into v_sid FROM sitetb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT sid FROM kam_report_ttn
  WHERE sid = sitetb.sid
) and cid = v_cid and sptid = v_sptid;

---insert into table---
insert into KAM_REPORT_TTN (sid) 
values (v_sid);

---update comments---
UPDATE KAM_REPORT_TTN SET comments = (SELECT addeddate || ', ' || responseperson || ': ' || candidatenote || ' '  FROM candidatetb_extra)
where sid = v_sid order by noteid desc;
UPDATE KAM_REPORT_TTN SET comments2 = (SELECT addeddate || ', ' || responseperson || ': ' || sitenote  || ' '  FROM sitetb_extra)
where sid = v_sid order by noteid desc;

   dbms_output.put_line 
   (v_sid || '/' ||v_sidcount); 
END; 
/  

Errors:

ORA-06550: line 29, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 27, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 33, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 31, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error at Line: 7 Column: 0

You will want to provide the full error stack.

ORA-06550: line 29, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 27, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 33, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 31, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error at Line: 7 Column: 0

Perhaps if you explained what you're trying to do with those updates, someone can suggest the proper way to do it. An order by clause isn't going to work.

This looks like you are trying to apply an order by on an update statement:
order by noteid desc;

I guess you meant to include that in the select subquery so:
UPDATE KAM_REPORT_TTN SET comments = (SELECT addeddate || ', ' || responseperson || ': ' || candidatenote || ' '  FROM candidatetb_extra     where sid = v_si)

I'm not sure if you have the where clause in the right place or not.

when i try this: UPDATE KAM_REPORT_TTN SET comments = (SELECT addeddate || ', ' || responseperson || ': ' || candidatenote || ' '
FROM candidatetb_extra order by noteid desc)
where sid = v_sid; i have a PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

updated answer.  Thinking that you don't need the order by at all as the subquery should only return one row.  I also moved the where clause into the subquery as that should ensure you only get one row.  Are you getting that error on that same line?

yes its working, but there are not only one row, so now i have a other issue :-)
